# windows 10 UWP UI design for mobile device

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am working on windows 10 mobile app. If I design an UI for 5' device, it doesn't look good on 5.2' device. Also on emulators of different screen size show messed up UI. Is there any work around this? Or do I have to design it for every screen size?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is with UWP that you can design for every screensize at once. It's just a responsive design you use (either HTML/CSS or XAML). But you have to use the right controls and settings.

Some guidance on how to design for various sizes can be found at [the MSDN design page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design). 
To create a dynamic layout with XAML, [see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml). There are various panel-types you can use to do the layout ([see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels)). But if you really want to build a responsive UI (or change it dramatically in various sizes) RelativePanel is your friend.

Comment: I want to do it simple way, like I used to do it for wp 8.1 apps. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, please avoid to have fixed Width/Height for your controls. With a Grid layout, you can set columns/rows and place your controls inside each cells. This is a first level to adapt properly your interface. In addition, UWP provides AdaptiveTriggers if you want to adapt the layout based on the screen resolution (cf. https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/07) for additional information. Last but not least, please check Design&UI documention on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/design.

Comment: I want to do it simple way, like I used to do it for wp 8.1 apps. Any idea?